# How to convert an ISO 8601 date to '/Date(1525687010053)/' format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, date-format, time-format

How can I convert a date value formatted as `9999-12-31T00:00:00Z` to `/Date(1525687010053)/` format in javascript?

I have this, but it doesn't work:

```
var datevalue = '9999-12-31T00:00:00Z';
var converteddate = Date.parseDate(datevalue);
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Are you trying to convert '9999-12-31T00:00:00Z' to a timestamp?

Comment: `var foo = '/Date(' + (new Date('9999-12-31T00:00:00Z')).getTime() + ')/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question, but your code is wrong. There is no `Date.parseDate()` function in javascript, only `Date.parse()`:

```js
var datevalue = '9999-12-31T00:00:00Z'; 
var converteddate = Date.parse(datevalue);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = converteddate;
console.log(converteddate)
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want to get the timestamp of that date. This can be achieved with the code below

```
var timestamp = new Date('9999-12-31T00:00:00Z').getTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do your conversion in just three easy steps :

1. Convert your ISO 8601 string to a Date object
2. Use `getTime` to convert your Date object to a universal time timestamp
3. Wrap `"/Date("` and `")/"` around your result

---

#### Demo

```js
function convert(iso8601string) {
  return "/Date(" + (new Date(iso8601string)).getTime() + ")/";
}

console.log(convert("2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z"));
```